# Restore ABS Mesh Blocks data into postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgis, ogr2ogr

I've downloaded the ABS Mesh Blocks data set. and i want to restore it into postgres db using ogr2ogr.

inside the downloaded folder i've below files

MB_2021_AUST_GDA2020.dbf  MB_2021_AUST_GDA2020.shx
MB_2021_AUST_GDA2020.prj  MB_2021_AUST_GDA2020.xml
MB_2021_AUST_GDA2020.shp

i write a query to restore all these data to postgres like this below

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" \
    PG:"dbname=db1 user=postgres password=adminsadmins" \
    -nln ptv.mb2021 /home/inshaf/Desktop/Assignment/MB_2021_AUST_SHP_GDA2020/MB_2021_AUST_GDA2020.shp \
    -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI \
    -s_srs EPSG:4283 -t_srs EPSG:7844
```

above query is successfully restoring the data

my question is don't i need to use other four files?
then what is the use of other files?

Comment: What is ABS Mesh Blocks?

Comment: I downloaded it from [here](https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/standards/australian-statistical-geography-standard-asgs-edition-3/jul2021-jun2026/access-and-downloads/digital-boundary-files)